# web client PUT method in MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to do **PUT** method for API service

Here is the code:

```
WebClient box = new WebClient();

var uuid = "40922d72-57dd-4fa6-bd64-f406f444dbb6";

if (HttpContext.Current.Session["JSESSIONCOOKIE"] != null)
{
}
else
{
    return null;
}

box.Headers["Cookie"] = HttpContext.Current.Session["JSESSIONCOOKIE"].ToString();

string sampleJson = "{" + "autoPresetTimes" + ":" + "{" + "0" + ":" + "Night" + "}}".ToString();

string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(sampleJson);

Uri uri = new Uri("https://my.zipato.com:443/zipato-web/v2/thermostats/" + uuid + "/config");

box.UploadString(uri, "PUT", json);
```

My problem is that this above gives me error 500 from server. I think because i dont send my body like this:

```
{"autoPresetTimes": {
    "0": "Night"
  }
}
```

On API page it says Parameter content type: application/json so i guess i should send my response o look like this above.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Your `sampleJson` already is json, you could just remove all the `+` and the `.ToString()` and don't serialize that string again.

Comment: I tried something like that   string sampleJson = "{autoPresetTimes:{ 0 : Night}}" ; and still i get The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

The json that you are creating looks incorrect. You need to put your keys within double quotes.

```
string json = 
    "{" + "\"autoPresetTimes\"" + ":" + "{" + "\"0\"" + ":" + "\"Night\"" + "}}";

Uri uri = 
    new Uri("https://my.zipato.com:443/zipato-web/v2/thermostats/" + uuid + "/config");

box.UploadString(uri, "PUT", json);
```

Note: You do not need to specify port 443 in your url. The default port for https is 443

Comment: I tried that too now, but still error 500. i just dont get what i am doing wrong. In their api page everything works ok so i am missing something:). See image in link http://s30.postimg.org/ohl1tbb4h/zipato.jpg